# Unix script - Needs suggestions to improve Performance (shell script)

Tags: ksh

I have a input csv file,  Actually I need to pick 2nd and 3rd columns values in the input file and needs to convert the timezone zone of both values (From PT to CT), Once converted I need to replace the converted time zone values in to the file.

**Note:** All input date values are in pacific time zone and I am converting into the central time zone.

Each row has 5 columns - comma delimited file

```
CHID-123456323,2017-01-09 17:17:58-08:00,2017-01-09 17:39:25-08:00,hello,123456733
CHID-123456733,2017-01-09 17:16:58-08:00,2017-01-09 18:04:09-08:00,hello,123456734
CHID-123433589,2017-01-09 17:16:55-08:00,2017-01-09 17:40:29-08:00,hello,123456735
CHID-123000789,2017-01-09 17:16:52-08:00,2017-01-09 17:46:41-08:00,hello,123456736
```

**Script:**  I wrote a below script , this gives exact result what I am expecting. But when the input record count increase it takes more time. For example 20 thousand records it's taking 1 hour 15 minutes.

can anyone please have a look on this script and suggest how to improve the performance?

**Script:**

```
while read i
do
    var1=`echo $i | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }'`

    var1_EPOCH=`date --date="${var1}" +%s`
    var1_CTZ=`TZ=":America/Chicago" date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -d@$var1_EPOCH`
    sed -i "${cnt}s/${var1}/${var1_CTZ}/" filename

    var2=`echo $i | awk -F',' '{ print $3 }'`
    var2_EPOCH=`date --date="${var2}" +%s`
    var2_CTZ=`TZ=":America/Chicago" date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -d@$var2_EPOCH`
    sed  -i "${cnt}s/${var2}/${var2_CTZ}/" filename

    cnt=$(($cnt+1))
done < filename
```

**here is the expected out put file**

Final Output file:

```
CHID-123456323,2017-01-09 19:17:58,2017-01-09 19:39:25,hello,123456733
CHID-123456733,2017-01-09 19:16:58,2017-01-09 20:04:09,hello,123456734
CHID-123433589,2017-01-09 19:16:55,2017-01-09 19:40:29,hello,123456735
CHID-123000789,2017-01-09 19:16:52,2017-01-09 19:46:41,hello,123456736
```

Comment: Don't use awk to split the line: use shell string functions ${i#*,} and ${%}(which is bash notation) to extract the dates. Instead of starting up sed twice, combine the two substitutions into one: s/D1/D2/g;s/D3/D4/g. Also, starting up date twice per line is a bit heavy, PT and CT switches to summer time on the same day, so the time difference is always the same.

Comment: This would probably get a lot faster if you rewrote it in Perl, simply because you wouldn't be starting 10 subprocesses per line (or rewriting the whole file twice for every input line).

Answer (score 1):

`Ksh` has enough builtin features for you.

The sample input file:

```
[STEP 100] $ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.5(2)-release
[STEP 101] $ cat file
CHID-123456323,2017-01-09 17:17:58-08:00,2017-01-09 17:39:25-08:00,hello,123456733
CHID-123456733,2017-01-09 17:16:58-08:00,2017-01-09 18:04:09-08:00,hello,123456734
CHID-123433589,2017-01-09 17:16:55-08:00,2017-01-09 17:40:29-08:00,hello,123456735
CHID-123000789,2017-01-09 17:16:52-08:00,2017-01-09 17:46:41-08:00,hello,123456736
```

The script:

```
[STEP 102] $ cat time.ksh
tz=America/Chicago
pattern='(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+)'
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
        c1=${.sh.match[1]}
        c2=${.sh.match[2]}
        c3=${.sh.match[3]}
        c4=${.sh.match[4]}
        c5=${.sh.match[5]}

        TZ=$tz printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %T)T' "$c2" | read c2
        TZ=$tz printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %T)T' "$c3" | read c3

        print -r -- "$c1,$c2,$c3,$c4,$c5"
    else
        print -r -- "$line"
    fi
done
```

Example output:

```
[STEP 103] $ ksh time.ksh < file
CHID-123456323,2017-01-09 19:17:58,2017-01-09 19:39:25,hello,123456733
CHID-123456733,2017-01-09 19:16:58,2017-01-09 20:04:09,hello,123456734
CHID-123433589,2017-01-09 19:16:55,2017-01-09 19:40:29,hello,123456735
CHID-123000789,2017-01-09 19:16:52,2017-01-09 19:46:41,hello,123456736
```

Make a 20,000 lines file:

```
[STEP 104] $ rm -f bigfile
[STEP 105] $ fourlines=$(<file)
[STEP 106] $ for ((i=0; i<5000; ++i)); do printf '%s\n' "$fourlines" >> bigfile; done
[STEP 107] $ wc -l bigfile
   20000 bigfile
```

Let's performance test it:

```
[STEP 108] $ time ksh time.ksh < bigfile > newfile

real    1m36.849s
user    0m27.376s
sys     0m46.741s
[STEP 109] $ tail -n 4 newfile
CHID-123456323,2017-01-09 19:17:58,2017-01-09 19:39:25,hello,123456733
CHID-123456733,2017-01-09 19:16:58,2017-01-09 20:04:09,hello,123456734
CHID-123433589,2017-01-09 19:16:55,2017-01-09 19:40:29,hello,123456735
CHID-123000789,2017-01-09 19:16:52,2017-01-09 19:46:41,hello,123456736
[STEP 110] $ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
[STEP 111] $
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to `sed` the  file inside your loop, but just write to the output. You can avoid some `awk` commands when you know that `read` can read more variables in one call. These improvements will change your code into

```
while IFS=, read -r chid d1 d2 rest
do
   var1_EPOCH=`date --date="${d1}" +%s`
   var1_CTZ=`TZ=":America/Chicago" date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -d@$var1_EPOCH`
   var2_EPOCH=`date --date="${d2}" +%s`
   var2_CTZ=`TZ=":America/Chicago" date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -d@$var2_EPOCH`
   printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "${chid}" "${var1_CTZ}" "${var2_CTZ}" "${rest}"
done < filename
```

You can upgrade to the `$(command)` notation, avoid some vars and double assignments with

```
tz=":America/Chicago"
tformat="%Y-%m-%d %T"
while IFS=, read -r chid d1 d2 rest
do
   printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "${chid}" \
       "$(TZ=${tz} date +"${tformat}" -d@$(date --date="${d1}" +%s))" \
       "$(TZ=${tz} date +"${tformat}" -d@$(date --date="${d2}" +%s))" \
       "${rest}"
done < filename
```

The logical next improvement is using `awk` (faster than writing a while-loop).

EDIT: add awk solution

In this case `awk` is difficult, since you do not want to use the `system()` call for converting the date (avoid calling other tools). When your csv has 1 timezone, you can avoid looking up timezone information with fixed values.
Skipping a lot of calculation will make the next `awk` a clear winner:

```
awk -F, '{
    split($2,A,"[-: ]");
    T1=mktime(A[1] " " A[2] " " A[3] " " A[4] " " A[5] " " A[6]);
    split($3,B,"[-: ]");
    T2=mktime(B[1] " " B[2] " " B[3] " " B[4] " " B[5] " " B[6]);
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,
       strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",T1+7200),
       strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",T2+7200),
       $4,
       $5);
} filename
```

When needed you can calculate another value for the time offset using `A[7]` and `B[7]`.

When above works skip reading here. Beneath is only an idea when you still need more imprevements.
Another strategy is avoiding converting the same date a lot of times:
When your inputfile has a lot of similar timestamps (equal day+hour), and you have a large inputfile, you can first convert unique hours and use these when
you are handling a large file.
Make a "translation helper" with fixed strings, something like

```
# Becomes dirty when you want to cut out the minutes/seconds:
cut -d, -f2,3 filename | tr "," "\n" | sort -u
# Hard to read/debug/maintain
sed 's/^[^,]*,\([^:]*\)[^-]*\([^,]*\).*/\1\2/' filename
```

Convert these dates and store in some mapping file, and use this for translating the filename might improve the solution more, but this should be the last thing to try (first try `awk`).